# Need help on ethstats app for private net

Tags: go-ethereum, ethstats

have anyone used the --ethstats for private net? I am trying to use it but I see below in the geth logs

> Stats server unreachable err="websocket.Dial ws://host:port/api:
> unexpected EOF"
>
> Stats server unreachable                 err="websocket.Dial
> ws://host:port/api: dial tcp host:port: connect: connection refused"

I have started the app eth-netstats app with below command

> PORT=port WS_SECRET=secret npm start

I see the app does not receive any data

Can someone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

ws://host:port/api, this server should start also.